# Show Covering Tests for NCover

Tags: nunit, ncover

In NCover (For NUnit) it shows which parts of code are not getting hit by any of the tests.

For code paths that is actually covered, is it possible to find out which tests actually hit them?

NOTE : This is possible in dotCover by JetBrains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) can't show you which tests are run since those **are run by an external test runner**, which NCover has no control over.

[dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/), on the other hand, integrates tightly with [Resharper's test runner](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html), from which it can obtain information about which tests exercised different parts of the code.